# Saving to new csv after using replace() (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with a set of data in a jupyter notebook and trying to replace numbered variables with names, and then save to a new file afterwards so I can use value_counts() and receive the values in names.

```py
numbered = [1,2,3,4]
fullname = [a,b,c,d]
df.replace(numbered, fullname)
df.to_csv('fullname.csv')

df_fullname = pd.read_csv('fullname.csv')
df_fullname
```

The replace works fine, but when I go to save it to a new csv and read it, it is back to the numbered version.

Comment: `df = df.replace(numbered, fullname)` you did not assign it to a variable and `replace` does not occur `inplace` unless you set that value to true: `df.replace(numbered, fullname, inplace=True)`

Comment: @It_is_Chris Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Umar you must do the replace inplace. Try:

> df.replace(numbered, fullname, inplace = True)

Comment: Worked like a charm!